# Is the "Deep web" really 90% of the internet?

Tags: internet

I find it hard to believe that 90% of the internet is the deep web. I saw this image and it doesn't really make sense:

[image]

I know that there's a lot of underground sites but I can't believe that it's 90% of the internet.

Comment: I might also suggest 90% of 'facts' on the internet are made up, just like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh absolutely, but it depends on your definition of the "Visible web", and it's components though. If we're speaking strictly about websites and their availability through a search engine then it's possible. It's quite easy for anybody with an internet connection to hook up a web server, and forward their ports. Instantly becoming part of the "Deep web". I find this definition making it hard to believe that 90% of it is hidden. Mostly due to there being no immediate advantage to doing this other than maybe the experience and bragging rights of "Hey look what I did". (Kudos to all the kids doing that by the way)

Let's expand our definition to include databases and web services, which generally aren't available through domain names or search engines. and if they are available through domain names, their likely not registered through the global DNS. With this definition it would most definatley exceed that, as most usable websites generally connect to at least one database or web service.

And finally, let's expand our definition of the web to all nodes! This includes things like your computer, router, internet modem (Or other dmark), up the the ISP and their complicated internal infrastructure which connects you globally to an unlimited possibilities of connections each defined by their own unique address (IP Address), including web servers, database servers, web services, ftp servers, mail servers, game servers, these possibilities are endless. The tip of this ice berg in this definition, would be the size of an ice cube.

Don't even get me started on virtual hosts...